# How to create Azure VMSS with accelerated networking?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azureportal

I created Azure VMSS (Windows 2016 Datacenter , Standart F2s). Somehow "Accelerated Networking" option was disabled (by spec , Standart F2s vm support network accelaration, also I have single VM running  with accelarated networking and exactly same VM Size and OS).

Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/create-vm-accelerated-networking-powershell#vmss , upgrade doesn't work. I got following error:

```
Cannot add network interface '/subscriptions/****/resourceGroups/*****/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/|providers|Microsoft.Compute|virtualMachineScaleSets|*****|virtualMachines|1|networkInterfaces|*****' with accelerated networking to an existing virtual machine '/subscriptions/******/resourceGroups/*****/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/|providers|Microsoft.Compute|*****|*******|virtualMachines|1' .
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create Azure VMSS with Accelerated Networking, you need to set `enableAcceleratedNetworking` to true in your scale set's `networkInterfaceConfigurations` settings:

```
"networkProfile": {
    "networkInterfaceConfigurations": [
    {
      "name": "niconfig1",
      "properties": {
        "primary": true,
        "enableAcceleratedNetworking" : true,
        "ipConfigurations": [
          ...
        ]
      }
    }
   ]
}
```

For more details, see the [Accelerated Networking in Azure VMSS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-networking#accelerated-networking). And there are some [Limitations and Constraints of the Accelerated Networking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/create-vm-accelerated-networking-powershell#limitations-and-constraints).

Comment: Thank you Charles. It seems  we should set options  before  creating resources  and  looks like VMSS  created  with  accelerated networking (I confirm which  there created "Mellanox ConnectX-3 Virtual Function Ethernet Adapter
"  network adapter  ) . In may previous case, first  I was  created  and I did  Redeploy template  with  accelerated networking. Thats why it  failed.

Comment: @NematjonRaxmanov Yes, you should set it before creating the resources through Template.

Comment: It was helpful, i will  accept  it  when i  got  15  Reputations (it is come from stackoverflow  rules)  ))